# Schedule process in jBPM with a start/end date time

Tags: jbpm

Is any way to schedule a process in jBPM to run at specified date and also define a time interval?

I try with a Timer, but I only can set a Time Delay and Time Period, what I need is a Start/End Date and the interval.

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of tasks you probably what to use Quartz to schedule the beginning of a business process. As any other scheduled task.
Cheers